# add lang resource to a html input asp.net

Tags: asp.net, localization, resx

Using a html control, how it can be created a lang resource?

```
<button id="btnCreate"> Create </button>
```

For german browser language to get button text: "schaffen" 
/For french browser language to get the button text : créer

Answer (score 2):

You can visit [this link](http://adamyan.blogspot.be/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html) for a nice tutorial on localization.
It basicly boils down to creating resource files which end with a .FR.resx or .DE.resx
Then your view would look like this :

```
<button id="btnCreate"> @YourResourceFile.Create </button>
```